# Cut a specific string from each row of input and show as one column in output

Tags: awk, sed

I have a huge tab delimited file in this format:

```
AN_NFE=6958     AC_SAS=1        AN_SAS=7704     AF=1.022e-05    
AC_OTH=0        AN_OTH=118      AC_SAS=6        AN_SAS=7360     
AN_NFE=2754     AC_OTH=0        AN_OTH=116      AC_SAS=14
```

Each row contains a value for "AC_SAS" but in different columns. I want to grep all records of "AC_SAS" with its value from each row, and output as one column, like this:

```
AC_SAS=1  
AC_SAS=6  
AC_SAS=14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep`

```
grep -o -E 'AC_SAS=[0-9]+' huge_file.txt > ac_sas.txt
```

Here, `-o` only prints the matching content, and the `>` writes to a new file (called "ac_sas.txt" in this case). Or you can omit the `> filename` part to print to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's:^.*\(AC_SAS=[0-9]\+\).*:\1:' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk to do this job and format is given below,

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^AC_SAS/){print $i}}}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s+/\n/;/^AC_SAS/P;D' file
```

Replace spaces by a newline and print lines beginning with the required string.